# Magento 2 page gets hanged during adding New Catalog Price Rule Condition

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, catalog-price-rules, catalog-rules

Magento 2 page gets **hanged** during adding New Catalog Price Rule Condition

What I am trying to do is:

Open Marketing->Catalog Price Rule->New Catalog Price Rule.

[image: Steps]

When I add a condition like : "category is ------" and click the product category selector it hangs the page and **category selector is never opened**.

[image]

Console messages:

[image]

When the page gets hanged after too much time it shows the below in console:

[image]

Comment: Show your console output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For quick fix add scope variable datatype `var` inside your loop of file **category-checkbox-tree.js**

Like this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/b7179ad97c0a406e41245d9d092a17df529a1768#diff-1119f9b28515cf267d3f8fc8c11ad59e

This is a bug in **Magento 2.2.4** which is fixed however will be released in **Magento 2.2.5** according to their GitHub Repo discussion.

You can find more details about this issue @ https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15121